# No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationDbContext'. in Asp Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1

i create this for Initial Database in ASP Core . i using this :

`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

but it show me this error :

> No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationDbContext'. Either add a parameterless constructor to 'ApplicationDbContext' or add an implementation of 'IDbContextFactory' in the same assembly as 'ApplicationDbContext'.

but i created a Constuctor . whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ?

ApplicationDBContext:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : ApplicationDbContextBase
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> siteSettings
        , IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
        , IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment
        , ILogger<ApplicationDbContextBase> logger)
        : base(siteSettings, httpContextAccessor, hostingEnvironment, logger)
    {
    }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.AddCustomIdentityMappings(SiteSettings.Value);
        builder.AddAuditableShadowProperties();
    }
```

ApplicationDbContextBase:

```
  public abstract class ApplicationDbContextBase :
   IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int, UserClaim, UserRole, UserLogin, RoleClaim, UserToken>,
   IUnitOfWork
{
    protected readonly IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment;
    protected readonly IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
    protected readonly ILogger<ApplicationDbContextBase> Logger;
    protected readonly IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> SiteSettings;
    private string v;

    public ApplicationDbContextBase(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    protected ApplicationDbContextBase(
        IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> siteSettings,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,
        IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment,
        ILogger<ApplicationDbContextBase> logger)
    {
        SiteSettings = siteSettings;
        SiteSettings.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(SiteSettings));

        HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        HttpContextAccessor.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(HttpContextAccessor));

        HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        HostingEnvironment.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(HostingEnvironment));

        Logger = logger;
        Logger.CheckArgumentIsNull(nameof(Logger));
    }
```

***Update***

I upload the my Project in Github . 
[GitHub](https://github.com/kia9372/DynamicPermisionWithIdnetityCore)

Comment: How are you using this DbContext class? Are you getting runtime error or compiletime error? Are you using any DI Container?

Comment: If you add your own constructor for the ApplicationDbContext class then the default parameterless constructor is removed. You need to readd it manually to your code: Just add _public ApplicationDbContext()_

Comment: @Steve i write this Constructor : `public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ApplicationDbContext")
        {
                
        }` but it show me this error : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I Update the Question

Comment: @Vanna I Update the Question

Comment: @Steve  I Update the Question

Answer (score 3):

- When the EF Core wants to instantiate the context, it will use the built-in dependency injection system to do it. Now it will find that you have more than one constructor here. Then it will throw an exception to tell you: `I don't know which one of these constructors should be used to instantiate the context`. To solve it, remove all of the other constructors (you should not have more than **1** constructor here). Just keep the one with `IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings>` parameter and remove the others.
- EF Core is able to handle all of the injected constructor parameters here using the built-in dependency injection system. But you should have only **1** constructor to make it work. It doesn't use the raw `new ApplicationDbContext()`. It will use `serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService` behind the scene to instantiate the context and all of its injected parameters.
- If you need other config params here, just use the injected `IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings>` and modify the `SiteSettings`, but don't add other constructors for that.
- If you have moved your context to another assembly, EF Core should be able to find the injected dependencies and you should provide the `--startup-project ../your_project_name/` too.

Comment: i download DNT Project . i copy your code . but still show me that error . i keep one constructor .

Comment: i Update the Question

Comment: There's no problem here. I could run your `_01-add_migrations.cmd` without any problems or errors. You should update your .NET Core SDK & RunTime. This is your problem: https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core#/runtime

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you don't have any default constructor in your ApplicationDbContextBase class and the ApplicationDbContextBase  can not be resolved by Dependency injection(see this [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection) for more information). change

```
   public ApplicationDbContextBase(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }
```

to

```
  public ApplicationDbContextBase()
    {

    }
```

or add the default constructor.

Comment: i use this : `public ApplicationDbContextBase()
    {

    }`

but it not work . still show me error

Comment: Please test your code this way : var x= new ApplicationDbContext(); see if it is possible to new your ApplicationDbContext without any parameter. if you can do that then there should not be any problem (ite's just for test don't use it into your code )

Comment: I Update the Question

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApplicationDbContextBase
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        IOptionsSnapshot<SiteSettings> siteSettings
        , IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
        , IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment
        , ILogger<ApplicationDbContextBase> logger)
        : base(siteSettings, httpContextAccessor, hostingEnvironment, logger)
    {
}
```

In this base keyword in used for send the data ApplicationDbContextBase Not ApplicationDbContext.

the ApplicationDbContext and ApplicationDbContext class need to pass mulitple paramters.so, the class say No parameterless constructor was found on 'ApplicationDbContext'. If you need to pass parameter. otherwise create  constructor without parameter.
Like

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApplicationDbContextBase
{
public ApplicationDbContext() 
 {
 }
}
```

and pass base parameter.

If you are Using in DI register all required Objects.
I Think It's Helpful for Identify and solve problem.

Comment: it show me this error : `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: I Update the Question